# Serializable in Intent/Bundle not working

Tags: android, android-intent, serialization

I moved the Model to an external Dependency so I can reuse it on Server and other Parts. But now I'm having the Problem that when I serialize to Intents Extra and then deserialize in BroadcastReceiver the deserialized Object is not null but it's Properties have the default Values like null (for the Strings) or 0 (for int or long).

This is excerpt from the Models Class:

```
public class Measurement extends Event implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 8246754793603601250L;
  /* Some other Stuff */
}
```

And this from Serialization:

```
List<Measurement> measurements = new ArrayList<Measurement>();
/* measurements get filled */
extras.putSerializable(Intents.EXTRA_MEASUREMENTS, (Serializable) measurements);
```

And this from Deserialization:

```
List<Measurement> measurements = (List<Measurement>) intent.getSerializableExtra(Intents.EXTRA_MEASUREMENTS);
```

Comment: does `Measurement` implement `Serializable`?

Comment: Of course; see above Code-Snippet ;)

Comment: what is `Event` ? is it `Serializable` ?

Comment: @GeneralOfTheFelixLegions please provide `measurements` declaration

Comment: A Class that contains some common Stuff like a Timestamp, ID and so.

Comment: @GeneralOfTheFelixLegions then why do you want to cast `A class` to `List<T>`?

Comment: @gio What do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All members of `Measurement` and members of its members (recursion) would be `Serializable`

Comment: Yeah, I just stumbled upon it myself. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. Problem was that the underlying Class Event didn't implement Serializable. Looks like this got lost during Refactoring and moving to an external Dependency.

Thanks to everybody.